# How to auto select the next date in the second calendar in "CalendarExtender"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 6 calenders on my form

```
DateFrom1 and DateTo1
DateFrom2 and DateTo2
DateFrom3 and DateTo3
```

My calenders always open by using today date, however, I don't need it.

I want that when my user select 20/2/2013 from DateFrom1 (calender) and after that when my user click on DateTO1 (calender) it must autoselect 21/2/2013 in open calender.

And if he clicks on DateFrom2 (calender) it should show with auto select (22/2/2013) in the calender view.

How can I do this in asp.net?

Note:
     I Am using `CalendarExtender`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onClientShown` javascript event to set the `To`-date according to the `From`-date via the extender's `set_selectedDate`-function:

```
<cc1:calendarextender ID="DateTo1"
    OnClientShown="clientShown" ...
```

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clientShown(sender, args) {
        var extender= $find('DateFrom1');
        sender.set_selectedDate(extender._selectedDate);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @princ_sameer: Yes, of course. But that is no porblem at all (i thought). Just set the `txtDateTo1.Text = DateTime.Parse(txtDateFrom1.Text).ToString()`. But why do you want to postback to the server to just set the text of another textbox when you can do this without a postback?

Comment: @princ_sameer: If this answer helped to solve it you should consider to accept it. You're welcome.